# Binomial Formula vs Naive Definition of Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following question:

A manufacturing plant produces a product with a 20% defect rate. You select 5 random items at the end of the line. What is the probability of having 1 defective item in the sample?

I'm having trouble aligning the "Naive Definition or Probability" with the binomial formula.

$$\begin{align}
Naive \ Probability &= \frac{Desired \ Outcome}{Total \ Possible Outcomes}\\
& = \frac{5 \choose 1}{\frac{5!}{2!}} \\
& = 0.0833 
\end{align}$$

Based on this result, it seems to me that the probability of obtaining a 20% default rate should be 8.3%, however the binomial formula shows 0.4096. Could someone please explain where I am mistaken in my reasoning?

$$\begin{align} 
Binomial Probability &= p^x (1-p)^{n-x} \\
&= 0.2^1*(0,8)^4* {5 \choose 1} \\
&= 0.4096
\end{align}$$

Comment: There are 32 possible outcomes, and they don't all have the same probability.

Comment: how did you get 32?

Comment: Each of the items can either be defective or not.

Comment: Oh i see 2^n. Thanks!

Comment: How did you get $\frac {5!}{2!}$ for total possible outcomes?  Even fixing the number of outcomes to $32$ doesn't solve the problem.  The naive probability formula assumes that all the outcomes are equally probably, but that is not the case here.  It would be like claiming the probability of getting a $6$ when rolling a die is $\frac 12$ because there are two outcomes:  a $6$ or not a $6$.